# How to store a value of variables in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm now in laravel, I working on attendence system and I want to store in the database the value of variable (`$diff` & `$status`) where I calculate the difference between the times and show the status of employees attendance.

How can I do that?  Here is my code:

```
@foreach($data2 ?? '' ?? '' as $da2)
    @if($da2->type === 'In')
        @php
        {{
        $t1 = strtotime($da->start_time);
        $t2 = strtotime($da2->time);
        $diff = gmdate('i', $t2 - $t1); 
        if($diff <= $da->period)
            $status = 'Not late';
        else 
            $status = 'late';
        }}
        @endphp
    @else
        @php
        {{
        $t1 = strtotime($da->finish_time);
        $t2 = strtotime($da2->time);
        $diff = gmdate('i', $t1 - $t2); 
        if($diff <= $da->periodOut)
            $status = 'Not late';
        else 
            $status = 'late';
        }}
        @endphp
    @endif
```

Answer (score 2):

to store it in the database you wlll need to use a model, looking at your code it looks like you are trying to do everything in the .blade.php template file, you should be using your controller and model for this.

for example if you had an Attendance model, you could add the below into your AttendanceController

```
public function store($diff, $status)
{
    Attendance::create([
        'diff' => $diff
        'status' => $status
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I try to add the code you write to my controller and nothing changed. Is there is something I should add in my model or any where else ?

Comment: Yes you would have to call the store() method from somewhere, this is usually dealt with by the router so that would be in the web.php file but you need to determine what type of request to send. This depends on where $data2 is coming from. It would be much easier to help you if you provide more details of exactly what you are trying to do and more of the code you are using.

Comment: $data2 is coming from the mobile app that we used to take the fingerprint. here is my route Route::resource('/Attandence','AttandenceController').  the idea is from the website side (attendance system) we determine the shift and from the mobile app it send the time for employee attendance.In the .blade above i do compere the times and set the different between the times in $diff and based on that i determine the status in $status but I need to save the 2 variables in the database.

Comment: without seeing how you are getting $data2 I cannot really help other than to say call store() after you have recieved $data2.